# Is this a possible coordinate change matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

$B_1=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^3$.

$B_2=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis the we got after applying gram schmidt procces on $B_1$.
is it possible that
$$
   P= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    2 & 3 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$ is the transition matrix fron $B_1$ to $B_2$ ? 
I don't know how to even approach the question. I tried to find 
$$
   P^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0.5 \\
    -1/3 & 1/3 & -1/6 \\
    1 & 0 & -0.5 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$ but also then I didnt get to any conclusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do Gram-Schmidt on $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ and get $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, then $u_1$ will always end up as a multiple of $v_1$.

This means that $P$ must have the form
$$ \begin{bmatrix} * & * & * \\ 0 & * &* \\ 0 &*&* \end{bmatrix} $$
But it doesn't. So it cannot be the corresponding coordinate change.

---

An extension of this argument shows that the transition matrix will always be *upper triangular*.

These conditions may be relaxed if your description of the Gram-Schmidt process don't require processing the basis vectors in order, but merely says "pick one of them you haven't processed before". But even so, the *first* basis vector to be produced will always be parallel to *one* of the initial basis vectors, so your $P$ can still only be the transition matrix if you scrambled $B_2$ after producing it ...

Comment: hi , so why in your answer its not upper triangular?

Comment: @KIMKES1232 How do you know that it isn’t? Only the form of the first column has been specified, which is the only one that’s relevant for this particular problem.